# LyX 2.1.4 on Mac (el capitan) problems with colon, comma, etc

Tags: lyx, mac

I think I'm having the same issues as described here:
[Lyx on Mac inputs diacritical marks instead of punctuation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167575/lyx-on-mac-inputs-diacritical-marks-instead-of-punctuation-marks)

When I try to type a colon, for instance, I need to hit "shift+colon key+colon key" instead of just "shift+colon key". Not only that (and this is why I'm not satisfied with the solution of the previous thread), when I do that, the next letter I type is decorated by some kind of a diacritic...

Also, when I type I get this small ">" sign next to the caret, I'm not sure if this means anything.

Example:
[image: Example]

Did anyone encounter this phenomenon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under preferences-> editing-> keyboard/mouse, change "primary language" to null [image]